# Uploading files to aws s3 bucket with boto3(python 3.x) maintaining the file structure?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I want to upload files from disk to aws s3 bucket maintaining different folder structure. I am able to make the same structure as on disk but need a little change in the structure.

The folder structure on disk is: `/home/userdata/uploaded_folder/uploaded_file`

The folder(key) structure I want to maintain on aws bucket is:

```
/userdata/uploaded_folder/uploaded_file/
```

My current code is like this:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
import os

conn = S3Connection()
path = '/home/userdata/'
bucket = conn.get_bucket('myBuck')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        #print(root)
        path = root.split(os.path.sep)[1:]
        path.append(name)
        #print(path)
        key_id = os.path.join(*path)
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = key_id
        #print(key_id)
        #k.set_contents_from_filename(os.path.join(root, name))
```

The above code makes the exact structure in the bucket. How to make the change in the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct line

```
path = root.split(os.path.sep)[1:]
```

to

```
path = root.split(os.path.sep)[2:]
```

first element in *root.split(os.path.sep)* is '' not *'home'*

Comment: yeah I tried that but then I'm unable to use the `path`. i get an error if I use `path` with the last line `k.set_contents_from_filename(os.path.join(root, name))`. Try using `path` in place of root and it won't work.

Comment: What basically is to be done is something like this: `s3.upload_file(disk_path, bucket_name, full_path_to_s3)`. I am not able to achieve this.